# Existe alguma clausula semelhante ao LIMIT no PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou usando PL/SQL e gostaria de saber se tem algum clausula ou sql script que seja semelhante a clausula LIMIT do sql, andei pesquisando aqui e achei o rownum < = X , mas não atende o que eu quero fazer.
Vou tentar explicar

#### SELECT

```
select 
  codfil, coditprod, qtde 
from 
  mov_lotevencto
order by 
  qtde desc;
```

#### Resultado

```
  CODFIL         CODITPROD      QTDE
1 106            65303          6098,4
2 106            65303          5450,4
3 106            65303          3648,6
4 106            50635          3050,8
5 106            58973          2947,8
```

Se eu usar o rownum <= 1 ele não traz a primeira linha do resultado acima ele me traz isso:

```
  CODFIL         CODITPROD      QTDE
1 106            56703          1,800
```

#### Dúvida

Teria como trazer só a primeira linha, porque quero fazer um select que mostre o lote que tem a mais quantidade de itens só a primeira linha.
Se poderem me ajuda eu agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coluna `ROWNUM`, o Oracle devolve o número da linha dentro do resultado da pesquisa.

O número é atribuido de acordo com a ordem em que as linhas são retiradas da tabela/sql.

Esta ordem é definida antes do `ORDER BY`, pois este é feito depois do "resultSet" estar criado.

Para o seu SQL funcionar corretamente você tem que fazer:

```
select * from (
  select 
    codfil, coditprod, qtde 
  from 
    mov_lotevencto
  order by 
    qtde desc
) where rownum <= 1;
```

#### Exemplo Prático

Fiz um exemplo prático

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/407cf/4

Comment: Obrigado Marlon testei aqui é deu certo, era bem assim que eu estava tentando, seria bem mais simples se tive se algo tipo um LIMIT ou o TOP, mas tudo bem valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @IsacOliveira para fazer o que você deseja no Oracle somente da forma acima. No SQL Server você pode usar `select top 1 * from tabela`e no MySQL `select * from tabela where LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2):

Em mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaxpto LIMIT 1
```

Em sql:

```
SELECT TOP 1* FROM tabelaxpto
```

Em pl sql:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaxpto WHERE rownum = 1
```